# Defining React CSSTransitionGroup animations with Stylus mixin

Tags: css, reactjs, stylus

I'm new to stylus and trying to figure out all the nuances.

For reference, React has a component to assist with CSS animations
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html

I want to be able to define animations using a mixin. For example, if I have a "login-button" animation, I want to be able to specify that the animation should be a fade animation by doing something like this:

```
animate.fade('login-button')
```

So I wrote a function/mixin like but its not working. When I run it through stylus, I get an error:

```
❯❯❯ stylus 
animate = {}

animate.fade(name)
  .{name}-appear
    opacity: 0

  .{name}-appear.{name}-appear-active
    transition: opacity .5s ease
    opacity: 1

  .{name}-enter
    opacity: 0

  .{name}-enter.{name}-enter-active
    transition: opacity .5s ease
    opacity: 1

  .{name}-leave
    opacity: 1

  .{name}-leave.fade-leave-active
    transition: opacity .5s ease
    opacity: 0

animate.fade('login-button')

^D
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus:593
      if (err) throw err;
                     ^
ParseError: stdin:26:1
   22|     transition: opacity .5s ease
   23|     opacity: 0
   24| 
   25| animate.fade('login-button')
   26| 
-------^

expected "indent", got "eos"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixin name cannot contain a dot. You can write it with `-` instead:

```
animate-fade(name)
  .{name}-appear
    opacity: 0

  .{name}-appear.{name}-appear-active
    transition: opacity .5s ease
    opacity: 1

  .{name}-enter
    opacity: 0

  .{name}-enter.{name}-enter-active
    transition: opacity .5s ease
    opacity: 1

  .{name}-leave
    opacity: 1

  .{name}-leave.fade-leave-active
    transition: opacity .5s ease
    opacity: 0

animate-fade('login-button')
```